# better failure/error messages for expected conditions in protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I am testing a form and I use ExpectedConditions.and to check if all of the fields are showing expected values.

```
   expect(
        await browser.wait(
            ec.and(
                ec.textToBePresentInElementValue(edit.driverFirstName, 'tesp'),
                ec.textToBePresentInElementValue(edit.driverLastName, randomName),
                ec.textToBePresentInElementValue(edit.driverPhoneNumber, 7887787887a),
            )
            , 7000
        )
    )
```

When it fails I only get

```
  - Failed: Wait timed out after 7356ms
```

Is there something I can do or some other pattern I can use to get error messages that tell me which condition failed?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a message in the wait, but it's not going to get you the details you want.

```
expect(
        await browser.wait(
            ec.and(
                ec.textToBePresentInElementValue(edit.driverFirstName, 'tesp'),
                ec.textToBePresentInElementValue(edit.driverLastName, randomName),
                ec.textToBePresentInElementValue(edit.driverPhoneNumber, 7887787887a),
            )
            , 7000, 'Edit stuff should have all the details I want.'
        )
    )
```

Separate your expect and wait statements.

Waits are use to ensure the page flow makes it to the right state or is done transitioning to the next view or page.
Expects can be used to instantly ensure the data on the page (without timeouts, and with details).

```
await browser.wait(ec.toBePresent(edit), 7000, 'Edit stuff should be present');
expect(edit.driverFirstName).toEqual('tesp');
expect(edit.driverLastName).toEqual(randomName);
expect(edit.driverPhoneNumber).toEqual(7887787887a);
```

This is a good resource for expect examples https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction